# VariableDeclaratorID exception in java while loop

Tags: java, arrays, variable-declaration

I have declared a String array globally. And inside a method in while loop when i tried to assign some value, it shows VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token.

```
//global declaration
String name[];

While (scanner.hasNextLine()){
String input = scanner.nexLine();
name[] = input.split(","); //here error - Syntax error on token "]", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = input.split(",");
```

By calling the above line for each line you read in the file you will be overwriting the contents of your array each time. If this is not what you want to do then I suggest using an ArrayList (which will scale in size dynamically).

```
ArrayList<String[]> name = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Then simply call

```
name.add(input.split(","));
```

for each line read from file.

Answer (score 1):

you will try this

```
name = input.split(",");
```

Comment: Hi Siva. Here in scanner giving a csv file and i need its content as cell by cell. Thats y taken a string array. Correct me if my logic is wrong.

Comment: @user3774445 your logic is correct. but you need to variable only while initializing array.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets `[]` are only used when you declare an array, initialize an array or access an element of the array.

When you just assign a value to the entire array you don't need them.

Therefore, change your code to :

```
String name[];

While (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String input = scanner.nexLine();
    name = input.split(","); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the concepts.